# RSS Generator from Joomla database

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, rss

Something challenging....

I'm using a simple php code to generate RSS Feeds from my DB which is for my Joomla 3 website.

I managed to get the list of items from the database but now I'm struggling to get the correct link for each item.

Here is the code which populates the items with the links...

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM bs_analiza ORDER by analiza_pk DESC");

if($results){ //we have records 
    while($row = $results->fetch_object()) //loop through each row
    {
        $item = $rss->addChild('item'); //add item node
        $title = $item->addChild('title', $row->h_team . " vs " . $row->a_team); //add title node under item
        $link = $item->addChild('link', 'http://dev.90mins.org/index.php?option=com_betting&view=pick&id='. $row->analiza_pk); //add link node under item
        $link->addAttribute('isPermaLink', 'false'); //add link node attribute

        $description = $item->addChild('description', '<![CDATA['. htmlentities($row->datum_ura) . ']]>'); //add description

        $date_rfc = gmdate(DATE_RFC2822, strtotime($row->published));
        $item = $item->addChild('pubDate', $date_rfc); //add pubDate node
    }
}
```

If I use simple link like www.my-site.com and add above will work but all items will point to the same page - www.my-site.com.

Any ideas how to attach unique links to items?

Comment: Why are you doing this when Joomla has a built in way of  generating RSS?

Comment: Adding `?format=feed` to any category will generate the RSS feed for that category. I don't think it's a good idea to generate the RSS when Joomla can do that for you.

Comment: In any case, if you really want to generate the RSS on your own, then you should use the Joomla framework to generate the links.